# Android Sockets not working in reality

Tags: java, android, sockets, server, client

I am trying to connect an Android device to a java server. It works perfectly when I use the emulator but when I port it onto my phone there is no connection.
The aim of the code is to send a value from client to server, perform a calculation on it and return it back to the client to be displayed.

This is my server code:

```
public class ServerTest {
public static final int PORT_NUMBER = 8000; 
protected Socket socket;        
private ServerTest(Socket socket) {
    this.socket = socket;
    System.out.println("New client connected from " + socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());
    connect();
} 
public void connect() {
    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {
        in = socket.getInputStream();
        out = socket.getOutputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String request = br.readLine();

        if (request.equals("end")) {
            System.out.println("Message received: " + request + ". Ending connection.");
            request = "End Connection";
            out.write(request.getBytes());
            in.close();
            out.close();
            socket.close();
            System.exit(0);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Message received: " + request);
            request = calculatePi(request);
            System.out.println("Output: " + request);
            out.write(request.getBytes());
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Unable to get streams from client");
    } finally {
        try {
            in.close();
            out.close();
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Welcome. IP address is: " + getIP());
    ServerSocket server = null;
    try {
        server = new ServerSocket(PORT_NUMBER);   

        while (true) {  
            new ServerTest(server.accept()); 
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Unable to start server.");
    } finally {
        try {
            if (server != null)
                server.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private static String getIP() {
    String ip = "";
    try {
        Enumeration<NetworkInterface> interfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
        while (interfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
            NetworkInterface iface = interfaces.nextElement();
            // filters out 127.0.0.1 and inactive interfaces
            if (iface.isLoopback() || !iface.isUp())
                continue;

            Enumeration<InetAddress> addresses = iface.getInetAddresses();
            while(addresses.hasMoreElements()) {
                InetAddress addr = addresses.nextElement();

                // *EDIT*
                if (addr instanceof Inet6Address) continue;

                ip = addr.getHostAddress();
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    return ip;
```

}

and this is my client side code on device:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView piResultTextView;
EditText addressEditText, messageEditText;
Button connectButton;

Handler handler = new Handler();
Results results;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    results = new Results();

    addressEditText = findViewById(R.id.AddressEditText);
    messageEditText = findViewById(R.id.MessageEditText);
    connectButton = findViewById(R.id.ConnectButton);
    connectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            connect();
        }
    });

    piResultTextView = findViewById(R.id.PiResultTextView);
}

public void connect() {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String hostAddress = addressEditText.getText().toString();
            int port = 8000;

            Socket echoSocket = null;
            PrintWriter out = null;
            BufferedReader in = null;

            try {
                echoSocket = new Socket(hostAddress, port);
                out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(echoSocket.getInputStream()));
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unknown host: " + hostAddress, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to get streams from server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            String input = messageEditText.getText().toString();
            try {
                out.println(input);
                results.pi = in.readLine();

                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        piResultTextView.setText(results.pi);
                    }
                });

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to read input stream from server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            try {
                out.close();
                in.close();
                echoSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error closing streams", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}
```

}

Comment: `String hostAddress = addressEditText.getText().toString();` We cannot see what the user typed in. Better put the typed in string in your code. Moreover i fear that already this statement will crash your app as you touch the gui in a thread. Which is forbidden.

Comment: `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unknown host: " + hostAddress, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` You can not put a Toast() in a `run()` of a Thread. Replace by log statements or so. Have a look at `runOnUiThread()`.
  `

Comment: Oh...  now i see. You could use `handler.post()` for the Toasts() too.

Comment: cheers mate, it has decided to start working without any changes which I am taking as a win!

Comment: Well gatulations! But then... you did not have any exceptions until now. If they come your Toast()s would let your app crash. Just try to put a Toast() in it that always gets executed and you will see.

Comment: I will replace them with logs, thanks for your advice.

Comment: Use your handler! Much better. Otherwise the user of your app does not get informed!

Comment: Just went to check it again and has stopped working! god dam it.